# Other Darshanas which are Vaidika other than Shad-Darshana?

Tags: shad-darshana, vedic

Or their other Vaidik Darshanas which aren't defined in Shad-Darshana?

Comment: Trika saivism darshana founded on Sivasutra is known as Shadardha darshana (6 and 1/2). This is also a Hindu darshana school from kashmir.

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay Wouldn't say Trika is a Vaidika darshana as Abhinavagupta pretty much rejects vedas as inferior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Sarvadarśanasaṅgraha](https://archive.org/details/SarvaDarsanaSamgrahaofMadhvacharyaPart1/Sarva%20Darsana%20Samgraha%20of%20Madhvacharya%20Part%201%20%28Hindi%20Translation%29%20Umashankar%20Sharma%20Rishi%20Chowkambha%20Sanskrit%20Series/mode/2up?view=theater), Mādhavācārya gives brief overviews of 16 darśanas, out of which 3 darśanas are nāstika viz. Cārvāka, Bauddha, & Ārhata (Jaina). The remaining 13 darśanas are āstika, which are as follows - Rāmānuja (Viśiṣṭādvaita-Vedānta), Pūrṇaprajña (Dvaita-Vedānta), Nakulīśa-Pāsupata, Śaiva, Pratyabhijñā, Raseśvara, Aulūkya (Vaiśeṣika), Akṣapāda (Nyāya), Jaimini (Mīmāṁsā), Pāṇini, Sāṅkhya, Pātañjala, & Śāṅkara (Advaita-Vedānta).

So, Mādhavācārya mentions 5 āstika darśanas (Nakulīśa-Pāśupata, Raseśvara, Śaiva, Pratyabhijñā, & Pāṇini), which neither fall within the ṣaḍ-darśanas, nor do they reject Veda.

Comment: I guess, pratyabhijna is the trika darshan of kashmir because they have a text called pratyabhijna-hridaya.

Comment: Aren't Pashypata Shaiva's Nastika, don't they not accept Vedic authority.

Comment: Do you have any source supporting that? Appayya Dīkṣita said that Pāśupata system is two fold, those that accepted śruti and those that did not. @Haridasa

Comment: @Bingming I have heard from fellow Vaishnavas they only accept Pashupata Agamas.

Comment: Well, Vaiṣṇavas are not reliable on this matter. Vaiṣṇavas reject even Śaiva Upaniṣads, Śaiva/Śākta Purāṇas, Śaiva/Śākta āgamas. Some even put down Śiva.  
And as per Advaita, Pāñcarātra is not even Vaidika. @Haridasa

Comment: @Bingming I am a Vaishnava...

Comment: @Haridasa ikr, I am talking about the pakṣa of some Vaiṣṇava sampradāyas (such as Śrī Vaiṣṇava). It's upto you though, what you want to follow. You want to follow the exclusivity of the sampradāyas of rejecting śāstras or be not exclusive and still a Viṣṇubhakta. There are Viṣṇubhaktas, who aren't part of the four Vaiṣṇava sampradāyas too.

Comment: @Bingming true I wanna be primarily Vishnu devotee, but also pray to Navagrahas and other devtas as well.

Comment: I see. That's fine then. You don't necessarily need to follow the pakṣa of Rāmānuja, etc. then. You can even be an Advaitin, and do upāsanā of Viṣṇu. Being a smārta, you can do upāsanā of more than Viṣṇu alone. @Haridasa 
In his Brahmasūtrabhāṣya, Rāmānuja argued that Pāsupatamata is Avaidika.

Comment: @Bingming traditionally speaking our family is Iyer, so Smarta, but I prefer Ramunajas philosophy, but at the same time I want to pray to other devtas, but Vishnu as the main or chief devta or deva deva if you know what I mean.

Comment: Also is Om Namo Narayana sinning if one doesn't have upanyanam?

Comment: @Haridasa japa of praṇava is niṣiddha for those who haven't undergone upanayana saṁskāra. You can simply say 'Nārayaṇāya namaḥ' in which Nārāyaṇa is in caturthī vibhakti, and comes before namaḥ. Similarly, a non-dvija can say 'rāmāya namaḥ', 'sūryāya namaḥ', 'śivāya namaḥ', 'durgāyai namaḥ', etc.

Comment: @Bingming okay btw is it possible to follow vaishnava and non-vedic sampradaya.

Comment: non vedantic not nastika

Comment: I don't know any non-Vedic Vaiṣṇava sampradāya, perhaps Vārakarī, but they uphold Advaita, so you can't call them non-Vedic. As for nāstika, you can't have a nāstika Vaiṣṇava sampradāya. @Haridasa

Comment: @Bingming I mean non-vedantic sorry such as Nyaya or Yoga.